# Laurent series expansion $\exp({\frac{1}{z^4}})$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I apologize in advance if this is very basic and usually I don’t have any problems with Laurent series, however I am stuck how to compute the Laurent series of $\exp( \frac{1}{z^4} )$ about $z=1$. I fail to see which algebraic manipulation would lead me to the result.

Comment: For which region ($|z-1|<1$ or $|z-1|>1$)?

Comment: It will be great if you add the complete problem like; whether you are given a specific domain to expand $f(z)$ or you need to investigate the nature of $f(z)$ at $z=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At $1$, it has a Taylor series with radius of convergence $1$.

I computed the first $3$ terms:  $$e^{1/z^4}=e-4e(z-1)+18e(z-1)^2+O((z-1)^3).$$